# How to get public user all posts from instagram, without instagram API

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api

I was trying to get posts from a public user's account on Instagram, I've tried almost every possible method but they are all returning 403 errors (access denied).

1. [https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=ded47faa9a1aaded10161a2ff32abb6b&variables={"tag_name":"{user-name}","first":25,"after":""}](https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=ded47faa9a1aaded10161a2ff32abb6b&variables=%7B%22tag_name%22:%22%7Buser-name%7D%22,%22first%22:25,%22after%22:%22%22%7D)
2. [https://www.instagram.com/{user-name}/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Buser-name%7D/?__a=1)
3. [https://www.instagram.com/{user-name}/media](https://www.instagram.com/%7Buser-name%7D/media)

```js
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Success!' ,data);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log('ERROR!', response);
    }
});
```

Above are the links from where I was trying to get data. As I've read Instagram are changing their protocols, is there any remaining way to get a list of posts from any public user without using Instagram API and without using backend code?

Thank You

Comment: `You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403` and access denied, it's not public.

Comment: what is not public? sorry don't get it. What I am trying to do it to get public user all posts without backend or instagram API. Instagram have changed protocol and I don't know if there is still chance to get this data.

Comment: Access is denied, it may be "public" only for registered users, ANYHOW, if you want to access posts without using API, you could make a scrapper.

Comment: sorry but can you be more specific what does 'make a scrapper' means? thanks.

Comment: I made scrapper and have got first 12 posts but is it possible to get all pages? any suggestions ? thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Your second solution should work. Try access this url:

```
https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1
```

It contains all the information for a user that is available from their page, including the 12 most recent posts, in a range of different sizes. As a side note, it does not contain followers or following lists

I have made a jquery plugin that uses this method:

```
https://github.com/kasperlegarth/instastory.js
```

Comment: why i cant call it from postman any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

## A PHP solution

You can add this in somewhere, it will pull the 12 most recent posts from a user and return the links for the photos in an array.
Here is an implementation

```php
function getPosts($profile) {
    $base = "https://instagram.com/";
    $end = "/?__a=1";
    $ls = array();
    $content = file_get_contents($base.$profile.$end);
    if (strpos($content, "is_private\":false") !== false) {
        return array(true, array());
    }
    $split = "config_height\":320},{\"src\":\"";
    while (strpos($content, $split) !== false) {
        $part = @explode($split, $content, 2)[1];
        $p = @explode("\"", $part, 2)[0];
        $content = str_replace($split.$p, "", $content);
        array_push($ls, $p);
    }
    return array(false, $ls);
}
$x = getPosts("najemi.cz");
$isPrivate = $x[0];
$posts = $x[1]
if ($isPrivate) {
    echo "Sorry, this account is private";
}else{
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        echo "<img src=\"$post\">";
    }
}
```

This would be used in HTML to display the 12 most recent posts of an account. You can tailor it to your needs by adding and removing things that are displayed, but apart from that, the function can be called with any username that exists.

## A solution for javascript, using AJAX

#### This solution would require access to a php file that would return the results

The Javascript would be as follows

```js
function display(array1) {
    array1.forEach(element => console.log(element));
}
var username = "najemi.cz";
$.ajax({
    url: "./getPosts.php?p=" + username,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        display(data.split("\n"));
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log('ERROR!', response);
    }
});
```

The php file, called "getPosts.php" would contain:

```php
<?php
function getPosts($profile) {
    $base = "https://instagram.com/";
    $end = "/?__a=1";
    $ls = array();
    $content = file_get_contents($base.$profile.$end);
    if (strpos($content, "is_private\":false") !== false) {
        return array(true, array());
    }
    $split = "config_height\":320},{\"src\":\"";
    while (strpos($content, $split) !== false) {
        $part = @explode($split, $content, 2)[1];
        $p = @explode("\"", $part, 2)[0];
        $content = str_replace($split.$p, "", $content);
        array_push($ls, $p);
    }
    return array(false, $ls);
}
if(isset($_GET['p'])){$p = $_GET['p'];}
$x = getPosts($p);
$isPrivate = $x[0];
$posts = $x[1]
if ($isPrivate) {
    echo "Sorry, this account is private";
}else{
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        echo "$post\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just with some CSS selectors you could do the trick. Paste this code in your chrome console, and you will get all the posts from some user (without being logged on instagram):

```
var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a")
var allPosts = []
for (var i = 0; i<allLinks.length; i++){
    var isPost = allLinks[i].parentNode.className.indexOf("v1Nh3")>-1;
    if (isPost)
        allPosts.push(allLinks[i].href)
}

console.log(allPosts)
```

Finally, if you want to improve this, add some pagination and repeat the same code.

Answer (score -1):

You get an 403 because you do not have a valid session. Web apps sessions are stored as Cookies (there is a sessionid cookie when you browse instagram.com).

**You need to include session cookie in your request's headers**.

An easy way of getting all headers of a valid request is go to Networks section of Developers Tools and copy the request headers or another format.

An alternative is to use [Greasemonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/) or [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) scripts. The will execute straight from the browser and using current session.

Comment: I've tried to do same, I put cookie into my request header but it was same result, maybe I was doing sth wrong. Please if you have time can you give me working example? thank you in advenced.